# Laravel 5.6 - User status check on error pages does not acknowledge logged in user

Tags: laravel

I have created custom error pages which include a navbar.

The content is determined by a check - `@if (auth()->check())`.

This always results in a nav bar for a logged out user, never logged in. Once back to a valid page/request the navbar displays as expected.

I have done some research but haven't found any answers that have worked. One suggestion appeared to work but then validation redirects were not including old data or errors.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Sessions are not initiated on error page routes by default, you will need to add the session middleware to all requests to have the session available on error pages.

Comment: Thanks @Joe, that got me to the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted by Joe in the comments...

In the file `app/Http/Kernel.php` - the line,

`\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,`

needs to be moved from the middlewareGroups web array to the middleware array.

Answer (score -1):

You should use:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
// The user is logged in...
}
```

In any case, as documentation says: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade

```
Authentication Directives
The @auth and @guest directives may be used to quickly determine if the current user is authenticated or is a gues.
```

Comment: Using `Auth::check()` has the same behavior.

Comment: So probably user isnt logged in at that stage: try <?php dd(Auth::user()); ?> and it's probably null... Then your error is somewhere else

Comment: Resolved by updating middleware in Kernel.php - see my answer.